# Flutter Menu Not Over Riding Main Menu When Navigate

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using footer menu to navigate som page aside the main home page which already has AppBar with a title, I want it to be overridden.

[image]

I want it, if I navigate from Home page to meditation page, I want the menu to overridden to "MEDITATION".

Here's my  footer menu:

```
 class Footer extends StatefulWidget {
  // Footer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FooterState createState() => _FooterState();
}

class _FooterState extends State<Footer> {
  var _selectedIndex = 0;
  final pages = [
    Dashboard(),
    Health(),
    Meditation(),
    Sleep(),
    Sounds(),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedIndex = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return GestureDetector(
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: dbShadowColor,
              offset: Offset.fromDirection(3, 1),
              spreadRadius: 1,
              blurRadius: 5)
        ]),
        child: Db5BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <Db5BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            Db5BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: db5_ic_home),
            Db5BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: db5_ic_heart),
            Db5BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: db5_ic_meditate),
            Db5BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: db5_ic_sleep),
            Db5BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: db5_ic_sounds),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: db5_icon_color, size: 24),
          selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: db5_colorPrimary, size: 24),
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          type: Db5BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: pages[_selectedIndex],
      ),
    );
    // );
  }
}
```

Here's my Meditation Page code:

```
 class Meditation extends StatefulWidget {
  Meditation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MeditationState createState() => _MeditationState();
}

class _MeditationState extends State<Meditation> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: appStore.scaffoldBackground,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            "Meditate",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          )),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                child: text(
                  meditation_text_title,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how I rendered my footer on the main HOME PAGE:

```
   return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: db5_white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: sh_textColorPrimary),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
        title: text(title,
            textColor: sh_colorPrimary,
            fontFamily: fontBold,
            fontSize: textSizeNormal),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Dashboard(),
          Footer(),
        ],
      ),
);
```

Am I doing it wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should implement your screens.

```
// Name the class whatever you like
class ScreensController extends StatefulWidget {
const ScreensController({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_ScreensControllerState createState() => _ScreensControllerState();
}

class _ScreensControllerState extends State<ScreensController> {
   int _selectedIndex = 0;

 List<String> mainScreensTitles = [
'Dashboard',
'Health',
'Meditation',
'Sleep',
'Sounds'
];

List<Widget> screens= [
Dashboard(),
Health(),
Meditation(),
Sleep(),
Sounds(),
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(

  // Indexed stack is used to prevent page rebuilds when navigating between the 
  //screens
  body: IndexedStack(
    index: _selectedIndex,
    children: screens,
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    //Toggle these booleans if needed
    showSelectedLabels: false,
    showUnselectedLabels: false,
    onTap: (newScreenIndex) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = newScreenIndex;
      });
    },
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
        label: mainScreensTitles[0],
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_outline),
        label: mainScreensTitles[1],
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
        label: mainScreensTitles[2],
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
        label: mainScreensTitles[3],
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
        label: mainScreensTitles[4],
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
  ),
);
}
}
```

Implementation of some of your screens:

Dashboard & Meditation:

```
class Dashboard extends StatelessWidget {
const Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Dashboard'),
  ),
  body: Center(child: Text('Dashboard coming soon')),
);
}
}

class Meditation extends StatelessWidget {
const Meditation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Meditation'),
  ),
  
  body: Center(child: Text('Meditation coming soon')),
);
}
}
```

Comment: I want the HomePage Menu "Home" To be Overridden to "Meditation" on the AppBar. Not on the same footer. Is the a solution to that?

Comment: Remember, "Meditation" is a page on it own.

Comment: Like, I want the home AppBar to be overridden with the new page AppBar "Meditation"

Comment: every  widget in the screens list is a page on its own